# ASP.net C# Name gridview columns after custom DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there the possibility to give a gridview's columns a custom name using programming code (C#) ?

F.E. I databind my gridview (which is empty in my aspx, except for the layout) using following code :

```
SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT M.Mod_ID, M.Mod_Naam, M.Mod_Omschrijving, M.Taal_Id, M.User_ID FROM Toewijzing T, Model M WHERE T.User_ID = '" + Session["userid"].ToString() + "' AND T.Toe_Status = '" + "ja" + "' AND M.Mod_ID = T.Mod_ID", con);

dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

gvIngevuld.DataSource = dr;
gvIngevuld.DataBind();

dr.Close();
```

How do I give these columns a custom name? Like F.E. "Modelnr." for the first column, "Modelnaam" for the 2nd, etc.

Also I was wondering if there was an option to enable paging (per 20 records) and to enable sorting ?

Any help is welcome !

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your `SQL` query can like

```
SELECT M.Mod_Naam as [Modelnaam] FROM Toewijzing T, Model M
```

**SQL Alias Syntax for Columns**

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name
```

By C#

```
    GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header";
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Any idea how to enable sorting and paging ?